# past continuous or present perfect continuous

Tags: past-continuous, present-perfect-progressive

If I play football since I was eight years old and still I am playing football I should say I have been playing football since I was eight.

But if I started playing football when I was eight and then stopped it 2 years later(now I retire from playing football) I should say I was playing football since I was eight?

So am I correct?

Because I have learned that present perfect continuous is for events that are connected to now but past continuous is finished in the past. ([example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254883/the-difference-between-past-continuous-and-present-perfect-continuous))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you started playing when you were eight and are still playing:

> I **have been playing** football since I was eight.

If you started playing when you were eight but are no longer playing:

> I **played** football since I was eight.

Although, more idiomatically, this would probably be rephrased as something like:

> I **played** football *from the age of* eight.

We normally use the simple past for something that is over and done with.

---

Only if we are talking about a discrete event in the past, generally something that is described as being interrupted, would we use the past continuous:

> I **was playing** football last weekend *when* I broke my leg.

Comment: Can the Present Perfect be possible with "later" adjunct (and other adverbials of the kin)? "He had been let loose from prison, but two years later he HAS PERPETRATED a series of criminal violations and he has never been taken up ever since." Here I mean that since "two years later" after having been released from the quod he has been making violations of the law again. Thank you!